# Generate sequence diagram from source code using Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2.0

Tags: java, sequence, diagram, jdeveloper

I have Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2.0 setup on my local machine to work on an existing project. I would like to generate Sequence diagram from the existing Java source. How do we achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. You can probably create an uml class from java code but nothing more.